# Get-put principles in Java generics

Tags: java, generics, overriding, bounded-wildcard

I was learning Java generics lately and came across the so-called "get-put" principle, i.e. which kind of wildcards allow you to add or remove certain types of objects from a collection (reference, e.g. https://flylib.com/books/en/4.79.1.18/1/).

My problem is, it is said that you cannot get anything but Object(s) from a collection that uses `<? super SomeClass>`. But the following code is perfectly valid:

```
List<? super A> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new A());
System.out.println((list.get(0).toString()));
```

where

```
class A{
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "super.toString();";
    }
}
```

The funny thing is, it really uses the overridden toString(), contrary to the principle.

Furthermore,

```
 A a = list.get(0);
```

fails.

Could anyone explain what's the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing unexpected is happening here. Let's run through the steps:

```
List<? super A> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

We have a `List` of `?`, which are above `A` in the class hierarchy. Every `?` is an `Object`, so we can think of it as a `List<Object>`. Proceeding onwards...

```
list.add(new A());
System.out.println((list.get(0)
```

All good so far - `list` has an `A` inside, and it is fetched as an `Object`.

```
                               .toString()));
```

We call `toString`, which is invoked on an `Object` (the `A`). Dynamic dispatch proceeds to invoke the `A`'s `toString` method (the lowest definition from the type hierarchy). However this is perfectly legal because `toString` is defined for `Object` as well as for `A`. Moving on...

```
 A a = list.get(0); //oops!
```

This breaks, as expected, because we try to convert an `Object` from a `List<Object>` into an `A`, without a cast (e.g. `A a = (A) list.get(0);`).

Answer (score 1):

The reference type of `list.get()` in this case is `Object`, and that class declares `toString()` so you are allowed to call it.

But Java uses [dynamic dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch) to choose which method to execute. And since the runtime type of the object is `A`, that's the version that is called.

Your code is equivalent to this:

```
Object obj = new A();
System.out.println(obj.toString()); /* Prints A's version */
A a = obj; /* Fails to compile. */
```

As you can see, the behavior has nothing to do with generics.

Comment: but why doesn't the compiler complain that I try accessing a lower-bounded collection, as the book says it should?

Comment: @AvramPop I don't understand your question. Can you indicate which line of code the book says should be a compilation error?

Comment: System.out.println((list.get(0).toString())); - getting should be forbidden from a lower bounded generic.

Comment: @AvramPop If your book says that's forbidden, it's wrong. You can invoke any (accessible) method of a generic type; a lower bound doesn't magically make a previously callable method uncallable. What the book *should* say is that the type of the result is unbound. All you know about it is that it is-an `Object` (because all classes extend `Object`). I think that remark is referring to what you have discovered: `A a = list.get(0);` doesn't work, but it's because the compile-time type of the result of `list.get(0)` is `Object` rather than `A`, not because `get()` is somehow forbidden.

Comment: I think the problem was with the proper understanding of the concepts - the thing that you said that get() is not somehow forbidden, that explained the whole thing. thanks